# Liquibase error IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql, liquibase-maven-plugin, liquibase-cli, liquibase-pro

I am using Liquibase tool for database migration from one database(MSSQL) to other database(MSSQL). I am able to generate change xml file using generateChangeLog command which has create and insert queries. so far its good.

Now when I try to execute update command then it fails with below reason:

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot insert explicit value
> for identity column in table ‘TableName’ when IDENTITY_INSERT is set
> to OFF.

It works fine if I manually add below tag in change xml file,

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HOSTGROUP ON;
```

Insert queries here…

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HOSTGROUP OFF;
```

But I am looking for automated way.

Is there any option in generateChangeLog command to add above tag automatically? Please help.